# Is there a way to reset ETH balance in hardhat test cases?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, test

I have been trying to create a test case file in which I have multiple it statements and a few of them consist of functions that are payable in nature. When I run the test cases, with every case passed, the user's ETH balance decreases(due to gas). So, I was wondering if there is a way to reset the ETH balance to its original value. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Consider using [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) and you can just use the [`deal`](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/deal?highlight=deal#deal) cheatcode to set any ETH balance to any address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the hardhat method [`hardhat_setBalance`](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#hardhat_setbalance) during tests.

Alternatively you can revert all state changes by taking / reverting back to [snapshots](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#evm_snapshot).

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

correction based on the answer from ikijong, the answer is yes.

A couple of other options spring to mind depending on what you need to do

1. if your test doesn't rely on the state of previous transactions, you can redeploy the contract before the next test and everything will be as before. Best way to do that is deploying the contract in BeforeEach block
2. hardhat makes I think 20 accounts available. If it doesn't affect your test, you could use a different account with a fresh balance.
3. before the affected test, could get the balance and take that into account in your results. you can also figure out the gas and take that into account in your results.

I have done all of the above in the past with option 3 as the most tricky, but sometimes necessary depending on what you're trying to achieve. Here is some partial code of when I've done that with chai. Hope it helps

```
  it("executes valid executions", async function () {

    /// @dev where the executor is also the receiver need to account for txn gas when check to address balance
    txn = txn0
    executor = srs[0]
    
    toBalBefore = await(provider.getBalance(txn.to))
    fromBalBefore = await(provider.getBalance(multiSigWallet.address))
    
    await expect(tx = await multiSigWallet.connect(executor).execute(txn.txId))
      .to.emit(multiSigWallet, 'Executed')
      .withArgs(executor.address, txn.txId)
    
    receipt = await tx.wait()
    gasCost = receipt.cumulativeGasUsed.mul(receipt.effectiveGasPrice)
    toBalAfter = await(provider.getBalance(txn.to))
    expect(toBalAfter).to.equal(toBalBefore.add(txn.amt).sub(gasCost))
    
    fromBalAfter = await(provider.getBalance(multiSigWallet.address))
    expect(fromBalAfter).to.equal(fromBalBefore.sub(txn.amt))
  

    txn = txn1
    executor = srs[1]
    
    toBalBefore = await(provider.getBalance(txn.to))
    fromBalBefore = await(provider.getBalance(multiSigWallet.address))
    
    await expect(tx = await multiSigWallet.connect(executor).execute(txn.txId))
      .to.emit(multiSigWallet, 'Executed')
      .withArgs(executor.address, txn.txId)
    
    receipt = await tx.wait()
    gasCost = receipt.cumulativeGasUsed.mul(receipt.effectiveGasPrice)
    toBalAfter = await(provider.getBalance(txn.to))
    expect(toBalAfter).to.equal(toBalBefore.add(txn.amt).sub(gasCost))
    
    fromBalAfter = await(provider.getBalance(multiSigWallet.address))
    expect(fromBalAfter).to.equal(fromBalBefore.sub(txn.amt))

...
```